# Resource is not grabbed when exporting to .JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, audio, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to get a better understanding of Java by creating a small 2D game. I feel like the best way to learning is by struggling, so I try not to get help on any problems I have; I just solve them myself. However, I've tried almost everything any I can't get my background music to play in my exported version of my game. All the images work and everything else pulled using the "    getClass()" method works, but the music doesn't.

Sorry I have to put all of the code from my BackgroundMusicManager class, but because I want to do things without help, my first version of my programs are usually very messy and require a lot of optimization. In short, you kinda have to see where things are called and initialized and whatnot to really see how the things work.

```
package com.cs.dd.audioManager;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLDecoder;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import com.nickgirga.dd.main.*;

import sun.applet.Main;

public class BackgroundMusicManager implements Runnable {
    //URLs
    public URL mmBgMusicURL = getClass().getResource("/audio/backgroundMusic/casual.wav");

    //Files
    public File[] bgMusics = { new File(mmBgMusicURL.getFile()) };

    public File bgMusic = bgMusics[0];
    private static Clip clip;

    public static int newGameState;

    public static boolean enabled = true;
    public static boolean asPlaying = false;

    public static Thread bgMusicPlayer = new Thread(new BackgroundMusicManager());

    public void play () {
        if (enabled) {
            try {
                if (bgMusic != null) clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                if (bgMusic != null) clip.open(AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bgMusic));
                if (bgMusic != null) clip.start();

                //System.out.println(bgMusics[0].getAbsolutePath());

                loopChecker();
                bgMusicPlayer.wait();

            } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void loopChecker () {
        while (true) {

            if (clip.getMicrosecondPosition() >= clip.getMicrosecondLength()) {
                bgMusicPlayer.notify();
            }

            if (!(GameState.state == newGameState)) {
                setClip();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setClip () {
        //System.out.println("setClip");
        newGameState = GameState.state;
        if (GameState.state == 0) {
            clip.stop();
            bgMusic = bgMusics[0];
            bgMusicPlayer.notify();
        } else {
            if (GameState.state == 1) {
                clip.stop();
                bgMusic = bgMusics[0];
                bgMusicPlayer.notify();
            } else {
                clip.stop();
                bgMusic = null;
                bgMusicPlayer.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            play();
        }
    }
}
```

After exporting this as a JAR with the libraries packed into it, the console reads:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: audio\backgroundMusic\casual.wav (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFloatFileReader.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.cs.dd.audioManager.BackgroundMusicManager.play(BackgroundMusicManager.java:33)
    at com.cs.dd.audioManager.BackgroundMusicManager.run(BackgroundMusicManager.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I extracted the JAR and found the file exactly where the FileNotFoundException points, so I'm left very confused. The audio works while running in Eclipse. The images still show in the export. Why will it work with the images, but not the audio?

Any help is very appreciated! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Instead of**

```
getClass().getResource("/audio/backgroundMusic/casual.wav");
```

**use**

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/audio/backgroundMusic/casual.wav")
```

In this way it will **look from the root**, **not** from the path of the **current** invoking class

Comment: I just tried that and it still plays in the editor, but not when I export it :(